# Java, updating map

Tags: java, dictionary

If map is defined as

```
private Map<Integer, Integer>   map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Updating the key works fine as shown below

```
public void increaseCountInFile(Integer hashCode) {
    if (mapContains(hashCode)) {
        increaseCount(hashCode);
    } else {
        map.put(hashCode, 1);
    }
}

private void increaseCount(Integer fileHashCode) {
    Integer key = map.get(fileHashCode);
    map.remove(fileHashCode);
    map.put(fileHashCode, ++key);
}

private boolean mapContains(Integer fileHashCode) {
    return map.containsKey(fileHashCode);
}
```

However, i wonder, can the same be done without having to remove the element from the map? (`map.remove(fileHashCode);`)

`++(map.get(fileHashCode));` Looks nice but Java does not like it

Comment: ++(map.get(fileHashCode)) does not mean anything.... map.get is not the same as map.set o__O

Comment: In my map it returns an Integer, which can be ++(ed)

Comment: and then it doesn't get stored anywhere... it returns a copy of an integer and anything you do to it doesn't change the underlying map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need

```
map.remove(fileHashCode);
```

`put()` will automatically overwrite the entry. You can shorten your `increaseCount()` method like this:

```
private void increaseCount(Integer fileHashCode) {
    map.put(fileHashCode, map.get(fileHashCode)+1);
}
```

Honestly though, I think you're adding too much abstraction in your code. It really should just be one method unless you have a very good reason otherwise:

```
public void increaseCountInFile(Integer hashCode) {
    if(map.containsKey(hashCode)) {
        map.put(hashCode, map.get(hashCode)+1);
    } else {
        map.put(hashCode, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `map.put(fileHashCode, ++(map.get(fileHashCode)));` invalid?

Comment: @JAM get can return `null` and you cannot use `++` on the result of a method.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more efficient that @tskuzzy's answer. This only performs the lookup once.

```
public void increaseCountInFile(Integer hashCode) {
    Integer prev = map.get(hashCode);
    if (prev == null) prev = 0;
    map.put(hashCode, prev + 1);
}
```

If you use TIntIntHashMap you can avoid using Objects or checking the previous value.

```
public void increaseCountInFile(int hashCode) {
    map.adjustValue(hashCode, 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The keys and values of the map are Objects (`Integer` in this case), so ++ does not work.. However, you can use `put()` without calling `remove()` first and the result is an overwritten value for the provided key.